# How to update values in a complicated JSON Array using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a request body (in JSON format) that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "l_ts":0,
    "af":{
      "lib":"xyz",
      "OS":"abc",
      "wdt":"2.63",
    },
    "frs":false,
    "g":"-v4d89ae6885b14baf91b102caaefea245",
    "tlc":[],
    "type":"meta",
  },
  {
    "s":1643895073,
    "evtName":"CONTENT_LIKE_DISLIKE",
    "evtData":{
      "contentId":17189,
      "likeContent":true,
    },
    "type":"event",
    "n":"_bg"
  }
]
```

Now before sending the request, I need to update the value of "contentId" field. I am using Jackson in my current project, so what would be the best way to update the "contentId" field in the JSON above.

This is what I have tried till now:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode requestBody = om.readTree(new File(pathToJsonAbove));
JsonNode requestBodyNode = requestBody.get(1);
requestBodyNode = JsonUtil.put(requestBodyNode, "evtData", "contentId", newValue);
requestBody = JsonUtil.put(requestBody, "[1]", requestBodyNode); // getting error here
```

The JsonUtil functions are as below:

```
public static final JsonNode put(JsonNode node, String key1, String key2, int value) {
    JsonNode jsonNode = node.path(key1);
         put(jsonNode, key2, value);
         return node;
}

public static final JsonNode put(JsonNode node, String key, int value) {
    return ((ObjectNode)node).put(key, value);
}

public static final JsonNode put(JsonNode node, String key, JsonNode value) {
    return ((ObjectNode)node).putPOJO(key, value);
}
```

I am not able to successfully put the node that I have edited (requestBodyNode), back in the requestBody which is the main JsonNode that holds the entire body. When I run the above code, I get a ClassCastException saying that I can't convert from ArrayNode to ObjectNode.

What is the best way to update the "contentId" field in the JSON above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to update just the *contentId* field you can identify the parent node of the *contentId* node and modify the child (moreover basically you have already made more than that with the creation of your function throwing the error) :

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode requestBody = om.readTree(json);
JsonNode requestBodyNode = requestBody.get(1);
ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) requestBodyNode.get("evtData");
objectNode.put("contentId", 0); //<-- 0 chosen as the new value
//it will show contentId updated to 0
System.out.println(requestBody);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Seems like I didn't really understand the tree model used by Jackson.

Comment: @AliZaidi It just a matter of experimenting with the Jackson library, unfortunately the documentation is sometimes misleading.